# Compare two dataframes and put the index from one df into the second one under conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare two columns (`one_one_3first` and `zero_zero_3first`) in two dataframes (`df` and `df_unique`). If the values from the `one_one_3first` column are equal in both dfs AND the values from `zero_zero_3first` column are equal too, I need to put the index of the row in `df_unique` into the appropriate row in column `unique_no` in `df`.

Here is the part of my input `df`:

```
              chr     start       end  genes_count               one_one_3first             zero_zero_3first unique_no
0     NC_064017.1   2753150   2912006           16  ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']  ['P1-22', 'P1-89', 'P1-92']      None
1     NC_064017.1   2932360   2996262            8  ['P1-22', 'P1-89', 'P1-92']  ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']      None
2     NC_064017.1   3003234   3038226            3  ['P1-26', 'P1-6', 'P1-92']   ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']      None
3     NC_064017.1   3038981   3107759            4  ['P1-26', 'P1-6', 'P1-92']   ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']      None
```

and `df_unique`:

```
                  one_one_3first             zero_zero_3first  genes_count
0    ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']  ['P1-22', 'P1-89', 'P1-92']           16
1    ['P1-22', 'P1-89', 'P1-92']  ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']           22
2     ['P1-26', 'P1-6', 'P1-92']  ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']            3
```

The desired output should look like that:

```
              chr     start       end  genes_count               one_one_3first             zero_zero_3first unique_no
0     NC_064017.1   2753150   2912006           16  ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']  ['P1-22', 'P1-89', 'P1-92']      0
1     NC_064017.1   2932360   2996262            8  ['P1-22', 'P1-89', 'P1-92']  ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']      1
2     NC_064017.1   3003234   3038226            3  ['P1-26', 'P1-6', 'P1-92']   ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']      2
3     NC_064017.1   3038981   3107759            4  ['P1-26', 'P1-6', 'P1-92']   ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']      2
```

I'd like to do it with `itertuples`:

```
for x in df.itertuples(index=True):
    for y in df_unique.itertuples(index=True):
        if x.one_one_3first == y.one_one_3first and x.zero_zero_3first == y.zero_zero_3first:
            x.unique_no = getattr(y, 'Index')
```

but it raises me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/emoranska/Pulpit/burak/homozyg_regions/unique_homozyg_list.py", line 30, in <module>
    x.unique_no = getattr(y, 'Index')
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

I've tried with `iterrows`:

```
for index_x, x in df.iterrows():
    for index_y, y in df_unique.iterrows():
        if x['one_one_3first'] == y['one_one_3first'] and x['zero_zero_3first'] == y['zero_zero_3first']:
            x['unique_no'] = index_y
```

but it seems no effect (in the column `unique_no` there are still None values).

Any advice on how to do it correctly? I guess there is some problem with getting the row index from `df_unique` and putting it into the column `unique_no` in `df`. Thanks :)

**EDIT:**

I reduced the input rows to be more clear.
I've changed also the code with `itertuples`:

```
for x in df.itertuples():
    for y in df_unique.itertuples():
        if x.one_one_3first == y.one_one_3first and x.zero_zero_3first == y.zero_zero_3first:
            df.at[x.Index, x.unique_no] = y.Index
```

and the output values are correct, but in the new unnamed column, not in the desired column `unique_no`:

```
              chr     start       end  genes_count               one_one_3first             zero_zero_3first unique_no    NaN
0     NC_064017.1   2753150   2912006           16  ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']  ['P1-22', 'P1-89', 'P1-92']      None    0.0
1     NC_064017.1   2932360   2996262            8  ['P1-22', 'P1-89', 'P1-92']  ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']      None    1.0
2     NC_064017.1   3003234   3038226            3   ['P1-26', 'P1-6', 'P1-92']  ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']      None    2.0
3     NC_064017.1   3038981   3107759            4   ['P1-26', 'P1-6', 'P1-92']  ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']      None    2.0
```

Any ideas why and how to change it?

P.S.

The `iterrows` function with the last line changed to:
`df.at[index_x, 'unique_no'] = index_y` works correctly but is REALLY slow (46 s vs 1 s with itertuples...).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please, provide a [mre]. It is hard to help otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```py
# columns to merge on
cols = ["one_one_3first", "zero_zero_3first"]

# merge and take index, setting this as df["unique_no"]
df["unique_no"] = df[cols].merge(df_unique[cols].reset_index(), how="left")["index"]
```

Using `how="left"` will join on the left, as required.

Comment: Great, thanks @Rawson! Very compact solution and 0.25x faster than itertuples :)

Answer (score 1):

you could merge your dataframe.
Since you can't merge on `list` data type, you would have to transform those column into `str` type, `merge`, then translate back to `list` type.

```
import ast
d1 = {
    'chr': ['NC_1', 'NC_1', 'NC_1', 'NC_1'], 
    'start': [2753150, 2932360, 3003234, 3038981], 
    'end': [2912006, 2996262, 3038226, 3107759],
    'one_one_3first': [['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28'], ['P1-22', 'P1-89', 'P1-92'], ['P1-26', 'P1-6', 'P1-92'], ['P1-26', 'P1-6', 'P1-92']],
    'zero_zero_3first': [['P1-22', 'P1-89', 'P1-92'], ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28'], ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28'], ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']]
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

d2 = {
    'genes_count': [16, 22, 3],
    'one_one_3first': [['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28'], ['P1-22', 'P1-89', 'P1-92'], ['P1-26', 'P1-6', 'P1-92']],
    'zero_zero_3first': [['P1-22', 'P1-89', 'P1-92'], ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28'], ['P1-12', 'P1-25', 'P1-28']]
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

# from list to str data type
cols = ['one_one_3first', 'zero_zero_3first']
df1[cols] = df1[cols].astype(str)
df2[cols] = df2[cols].astype(str)
df2 = df2.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'unique_no'})

# merge
temp = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['one_one_3first', 'zero_zero_3first'], how='left')

# back to list data type
df1[cols] = df1[cols].apply(lambda x: x.apply(ast.literal_eval), axis=1)
df2[cols] = df2[cols].apply(lambda x: x.apply(ast.literal_eval), axis=1)
temp[cols] = temp[cols].apply(lambda x: x.apply(ast.literal_eval), axis=1)
```